# Clustering Nodes in an Graph

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, graph, traversal

I need to be able to traverse through a graph efficiently from a starting point to and ending point with the best path. In order to efficiently process large amounts of data, I am trying to precompute similar nodes into clusters. A node is similar if it shares the same color.

I currently have a Node class, and ClusteredNode class, but am unsure on how to proceed. Ideally I would like an iterative approach (since a recursive one might break with large amounts of nodes).

`Node class attributes:
    int id, color;
    boolean visited;
    List<Node> neighbors;`

`ClusteredNode class attributes:
    List<ClusteredNode> neighbors;
    ClusteredNode visited_by; // The visiting node, prevents infinite loops
    int color;
    boolean isStart, isEnd, wasVisited;`

Here's a picture illustrating what I want to do:
[Node Visual.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Kej2.png)

Comment: Have you heard of dijkstra's shortest path algorithm? Is there some reason you need to cluster instead of using a well-known, correct, and efficient algorithm?

Comment: I think dijkstra's shortest path algorithm will work! Thank you. There are some states that need to be passed along to the nodes with similar colors, but I might be able to get this to work. Thanks!